# What is the largest chromatic number of a binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, discrete-mathematics

This is a Discrete Math/Combinatorics Question from my homework, but I don't really understand the question.

> Find largest chromatic number of a full binary tree given the following depths:
>   (Check all that apply)
>
> 2, 3, 7, 12, 200

I understand that the chromatic number refers to the minimum color that you can color a graph or tree with the adjacent nodes or vertices being different colors.

So knowing this fact, I'm sure that the chromatic number for all full binary trees should be 2 since you can use two different color nodes to complete the tree. But they want me to find the largest chromatic number, which confuses me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You might also want to post this in the Theoretical Computer Science community.

Comment: I second that. The best thing you can do code wise is turn this into a Graph Coloring Problem.

Comment: I agree with your claim that the solution is `2` (color in red the node at even depth and blue at odd depth)... Unless you have a non standard definition for chromatic number of a tree...

Answer (score 1):

All trees are bipartite graphs and therefore 2-colorable. One way to see this is that a graph is bipartite iff it has no odd cycles, and since trees have no cycles at all, they must be bipartite. Therefore, two colors suffice regardless of the tree size.

Hope this helps!